# Proving Summations

Tags: summation

I'm unsure of how to continue in my proof. How can I prove the follow through induction:

$\sum\limits_{k=66}^n {k-1 \choose 65} = {n \choose 66}$ where $n \geq k \geq 66$

Basis:Let $n=66$.
$$\sum\limits_{k=66}^{66} {66-1 \choose 65} = {66 \choose 66}$$
$$1 = 1$$
The basis holds.

Induction Hypothesis: Suppose $n=m$ holds for all $m\geq 66$

Induction Step: Consider $m+1$.
$$\sum\limits_{k=66}^{m+1} {k-1 \choose 65} = {m+1 \choose 66}$$

Comment: The basis holds, so then show that ${n+1 \choose 66} - {n \choose 66} = {n \choose 65}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{k=66}^{m+1} {k-1 \choose 65} ={m\choose 65} + \sum\limits_{k=66}^{m} {k-1 \choose 65}  \stackrel{\star}{=} {m\choose 65}+{m\choose 66} =  {m+1 \choose 66}$$

Where $\star$ holds because the identity holds for $m$

---

However, there is a little (well, not even) error in your "basis-step". $\sum\limits_{k=66}^{66} {k-1 \choose 65}$ is of course equal to ${65\choose 65}$. Indeed this is the same as ${66\choose 66}$